# Function setIntervall become faster after change router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slideshow, setinterval, router

https://protected-temple-97157.herokuapp.com/

here theres my app, if you open you see that there no problems on slideshow, the image change after the 6 seconds, but if you go to other router and then comeback on Home after the first image the slideshow become more faster

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.slide();
}

slide = () => {
    $(".slideshow > .card:gt(0)").hide();
    setInterval(() => {
        $(".slideshow > .card:first")
            .fadeOut(3000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(3000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('.slideshow')
    }, 6000)
}
```

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider [accepting one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you add a new Interval each time you come back to the site. If you look closely you see that the time difference between the slides varies, therefore multiple intervals are set.

You can prevent this by calling setInterval only once, initially, or use clearInterval to clear the previous interval.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the slideshow is faster, but you will get another interval that changes slides because you don't stop the previous interval when the component is unmounted.

You can put the number returned from `setInterval` on the component and call `clearInterval` in `componentWillUnmount` to get around this.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  interval = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.slide();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  slide = () => {
    $(".slideshow > .card:gt(0)").hide();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      $(".slideshow > .card:first")
        .fadeOut(3000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(3000)
        .end()
        .appendTo(".slideshow");
    }, 6000);
  };
}
```